# What is the White circle?

Tags: titlebar

Screenshot of corner of screen

[image]

Noob question but please can someone tell me what the white spot is to the right of the app icon (i.e. to the left on the title bar just after the app logo)? I'm using Ubuntu Studio 23.10 so the desktop is Plasma, It obviously does something but I cannot figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Ubuntu 23.10: this is the activity indicator which was introduced by the GNOME team for GNOME 45 (which is used in Ubuntu 23.10).
For details see e.g. https://release.gnome.org/45/, section "Activities Indicator".

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually using Ubuntu Studio 23.10 so the desktop is Plasma, but I'll check the documentation for that.

Comment: @T1moth Excellent that you now mention the desktop you use. However, edit your question and make that clear so people are correctly informed from the start.